# Recurrent Neural Network RNN - how to implement one output as input to the next iteration in Python Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

The FCC fully connected cascaded network with recurrent layer is shown in the figure below.

[image: Fully Connected Cascaded Network with Recursion]

It is required to understand how to implement a Jordan RNN topology with the following features:

x1, x2 and x3 are input signals that are measurements in different time series.
o1, o2 are outputs from the last prediction of the NN and o is the actual output

```
x1, x2, x3, o1, o2  -->  o
 2,  3,  3, 10,  9, --> 11,
 3,  4,  4, 11, 10, --> 12,
 2,  4,  4, 12, 11, --> 13,
 3,  5,  5, 13, 12, --> 14,
 4,  6,  6, 14, 13, --> 15,
```

The code below implements the network without recursion:

```
# Get features
x1 = [2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
x2 = [3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
x3 = [3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

# Get the labels
y = [11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0]

# Define the number of hidden layer neurons, one neuron per layer.
nr_of_neurons = 3
# Define the number of input neurons
nr_input_units = 3
# Define the number of output neurons
nr_output_units = 1

# Define activation of all hidden layers.
hidden_activation = 'relu'

# Define activation of all output layer.
output_activation = 'sigmoid'

visible = Input(shape=(nr_input_units,))
hidden = Dense(1, name='Neuron_0', activation=hidden_activation)(visible)
hidden_arr = [visible, hidden]

for idx in range(nr_of_neurons-1):
    neuron_name = 'Neuron_' + str(idx+1)
    merge_x = concatenate(hidden_arr)
    hidden_x = Dense(1, name=neuron_name, activation=hidden_activation)(merge_x)
    hidden_arr.append(hidden_x)

output = Dense(nr_output_units, activation=output_activation)(merge_x)
self._model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
```

How do I build to train a RNN with the above code? How to predict considering o1 and o2 are past output?

Comment: hey @Marcelo your question is not clear and your sample seems fine, although this `merge3_in = concatenate([visible, hidden1, hidden2])`  will be `merge3_in = concatenate([hidden1, hidden2])` i guess.

Comment: @Abdirahman the code is fine. The figure is missing one connection between the first from left to the last neuron. I am looking for implementation of recursion (refer to the red lines) while training and predicting in Keras/Tensforflow (Good catch! I am gonna edit the question).

Comment: @Abdirahman figure is now fixed and matches with the code. Would you know how to implement the red lines in the code above? Please, remember, the idea is to train and predict.

Comment: according to my understanding there is nothing missing in the figure, the red lines are time series features and the black lines are normal features, you have three hidden layers, each one having five raw inputs and the output of the previous layer as input. Please note the recursiveness can only exist in the hidden layers meaning the output layer will not be recursive. If that is clear we can proceed and i will point some sample codes can refer to..

Comment: @Abdirahman The topology named as "Jordan" neural network is depicted in the figure. The recursiveness for previous outputs to the current one is what is required.

Jordan network means recursiveness on the output of network as input, it takes in account the activation function. Elman network is almost the same, where it supply the potential of output neuron (before activation function) as the next one. You can see some definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network


Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.